# Check if Label already exist in Adwords account using Python?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I need to check if Label already exist in my account of Adwords. I am using Python and using Adwords API for it.
I created a Label using following code. Before creating this Label I want to check if this Label is already exist then not to create it again.

```
label_service = client.GetService('LabelService', version='v201409')
###Code here to check if 'MyLabel' already exist - please suggest
operations = [{
                'operator': 'ADD',
                'operand': {'xsi_type': 'TextLabel',
                'name' : 'MyLabel',
                'status': 'ENABLED'}
                }]
result = label_service.mutate(operations)
```

I can see with get operation of LabelService I can get Labels of specified criteria.
But I am not able to specify serviceSelector parameter correctly.

Comment: Honest question: Many commercial services use stackoverflow as a support channel, is this site an official support channel for Adwords?

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tour, you will come to know for what this site is. It doesn't speak anything about commercial or non commercial use. Its just a site for Ask questions, get answers, no distractions.

Comment: If SO is a sanctioned support channel (it is, for several ISPs) you can expect answers by paid staff from adwords. If it is not, you will have to wait for a good Samaritan willing to donate his time supporting an API from one of the most profitable companies in the world.

Comment: Thanks Paulo for your suggestion, the problem I put in Adwords Forum and got the solution. Thanks for your valuable time ! I am very new to Adwords as well as Python too.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, if you run `get` instead of `mutate` like this:

```
label_service.get({'fields': ['LabelId', 'LabelName', 'LabelStatus', 'LabelAttribute']})
```

It will return an object which contains all the existing labels and their ids etc in an account.

In any case, I just tested it, it will not let you create a label which already exists so you don't need to worry.